# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'MaskedEditValidatorDate' is undefined- Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a ASP .Net  Web application.

I can't access some forms:

`0x800a1391 - Java-script runtime error: 'MaskedEditValidatorDate' is undefined-  Internet Explorer 11`

But google chrome, safari, firefox browsers are working,

What is the reason for this error?

I uninstalled my old IE browser and after reinstalling, then not working

debug the project displayed following error **(EVAL CODE)** val.evaluationfunction = RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid;

```
val.evaluationfunction = CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid;

val.evaluationfunction = RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid;

val.evaluationfunction = MaskedEditValidatorDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

From Internet Explorer 11 
Delete temporary internet files and website files from tools internet option general delete.

Comment: You should expand on this to explain why this is useful and how it solves the problem.